# How do I cure Sanguinare Vampiris?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have Sanguinare Vampiris. I don't really want to become a vampire. How can I cure myself?

Comment: @George Stocker has a great answer that covers both these previous questions.

Comment: Something worth noting once you get rid of vampirism: If you get Lycanthropy, there are no negative effects, and it makes you 100% resistant to disease, so you'll never contract vampirism again!

Comment: @RavenDreamer Any way this could get merged over into one of those other questions?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There was a great walkthrough on how to cure Vampirism on Gamefront: due to that site's redesign, it's been lost, but here's the list, distilled:

- If it's within three days of becoming a vampire, you can cure the disease with a `Cure Disease` Potion.
- Activate any Shrine.  The Shrine of Talos outside Whiterun will do. Shrines will cure you of all diseases.

Since it sounds like you're a Stage 4 vampire, you should feed so that you're no longer stage 4. To do this:

> wait until night and drink the blood of a sleeping person. Even sleeping beggars will do. Just crouch/sneak and interact with a sleeping NPC to drink their blood.
>
> **NB**:  If you’re still having trouble drinking blood, remember that you have two useful abilities as a Stage 4 vampires — Embrace of Shadows, and Vampire Seduction. Embrace of Shadows turns you invisible, while Vampire Seduction will make an NPC calm and cease wanting to attack you.

Once you have contracted vampirism (e.g., gone beyond Day 4), you need to do the following:

- Speak with any Inn Keeper or Bartender about rumors. They’ll tell you that a man named Falion in Morthal is studying vampires.
- Find Morthal east of Fort Snowhawk. Once there, talk to Falion and he’ll discuss how to cure vampirism.
- He’ll tell you to get a Black Soul Gem. If you don’t have one, Falion will sell you one. Before being cured, you’ll need to fill the Black Soul Gem.

> To fill a Black Soul Gem, you’ll need to cast a Soul Trap spell on a human, then kill them. Any human will work, including bandits and enemies.

- You’ll need to obtain a Soul Trap spell, sold by any magic vendor.

> If you’re really desperate, try the College of Winterhold, or explore Whiterun to find a shop. If you don’t have high magic skills, just purchase a Soul Trap scroll. NOTE: The Mage for the Jarl of Whiterun, the Jarl’s Court Mage, should have a Soul Trap spell.

With a filled Black Soul Gem, return to Falion and talk to him to complete the ritual.

Comment: As an alternative, some people might prefer to use the Mace of Molag Bal to fill their black soul gems.

Comment: Also note that contracting Lycanthropy, a.k.a. becoming a Werewolf via the Companions mission "The Silver Hand", will get rid of vampirism. Of course, I'd only recommend this for people who actually want to be Werewolves, as it comes with side effects as well. I personally like being a Werewolf - vampirism, though, is really annoying!

Answer (score 10):

If you're fast, you can chug a Cure Disease potion or pray at a shrine.

Once Vampirism has set in however, you only have two options:

You can become a Werewolf.

**or**

If you harass enough bartenders for rumors, they will tell you about a fellow named Falion in Morthal who is working on a cure. He'll want Black Soul Gems though, so it won't be cheap or easy!

Answer (score 0):

In Dawnstar I think next to the mine there is a hidden chest (under ground) which when you look at you can open, it is FULL of goodies, which you can sell. One of them is a weapon which when you kill someone with it it actually fills the soul gem for you, a quick short cut. The vampirism is very annoying.

One other thing, when you go to be cured, make sure you have fed on blood before hand otherwise he won't cure you and will instead fight you. Best go to a farm wait to dark, take off your armour and sneek in whislt they are asleep

Comment: Most loot is random in this game so the weapon might not be there

Comment: Fair enough never knew that.  But this loot is a glitch, you can go back time and time again for it

Answer (score -3):

1:try not to go to sleep or else you will transform
2:shrines and potions of cure disease can get rid of it
3:if you do transform, there is a quest in dawnstar to remove vampirism

Comment: You're just repeating what the accepted answer said five years ago.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer With a lot less detail.