# I am a vampire without dlc. What do I do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started a new game today on skyrim. I am at my 2nd house, while my main house gets worked on. In my second house the skyrim has no DLC. I was playing as an Orc and I got in the dark brotherhood and then not soon after I started getting attacked everywhere I go. How do I fix this? I am not like the DLC vampire. I am in the thieve's guild and am a nightingale.

Comment: Being attacked as a vampire is not related to your guild affiliations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four stages of vampirism. When you become a vampire, you start at stage one. Every day that you don’t feed, you advance to the next stage. If you don’t have Dawnguard installed, stage four vampires are attacked on sight. So if you haven’t fed on anyone in at least three days, that’s probably why everyone is attacking you.

The Dawnguard DLC changed this, such that the player is never attacked for being a vampire except when you’re in Vampire Lord form, even if you don’t feed at all. If you usually play with the DLCs installed and aren’t in the habit of feeding, that could explain why you’re getting unexpectedly attacked without the DLCs.

To stop people from attacking you, feed on someone at least every three days from now on. To feed, you need to find a sleeping NPC, sneak up to them, and activate the NPC while you’re sneaking. Keep in mind that if any NPCs nearby see you, they’ll attack you and probably wake up your victim before you get a chance to feed.

For more information, see UESP’s article on [vampirism](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism).

Comment: Also note that you can [cure vampirism](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/45412/108003).