# Why did I become a vampire after I rejected the 'offer'?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently started the dawnguard quests and after completing the first quest, we get to choose sides. Be or not to be a vampire, right? I gladly rejected the 'offer' and continued to ply quests for dawnguard. The second quest for them was to recruit 2 of their old pals. Before stating the mission I went to riften for selling stuffs and train but all of a sudden I m a vampire. Message popped up saying that my vampire blood boils in sun.

Here's what I did exactly. I went to riften and since I had fast travelled it was nighttime so I used the wait feature for 10 hrs. Then this all happened.

I even loaded the last save and did all over again but even then the message saying 'Your Vampire blood awakens'. Is this a bug or is it because I was harmed by vampires during battle??

Answer (score 63, accepted):

What you've done is become a vampire the old fashioned way.

Whenever a vampire attacks you there is a chance that you'll contract [Sanguinare Vampiris](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sanguinare_Vampiris), you probably picked it up from one of the vampires in Dimhollow Crypt. Like any other disease it'll be listed under 'Active Effects'.

It takes three ingame days to transform into a vampire with the occasional slightly cryptic notification throughout though if you fast travelled all the way from Castle Volkihar to Riften and waited around it's quite possible you missed them.

While you can cure vampirism after it's taken hold through the [Rising at Dawn](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Rising_at_Dawn) quest the simplest thing to do would be to reload a save before you were notified that you became a vampire and simply cure the disease either with the right potion or just hitting up a shrine.

Comment: Look in your enchantment area and you'll notice a vampirism "buff"

Comment: ^ Fair point, added that

Answer (score 11):

> because I was harmed by vampires during battle?

That's probably it. There are more ways of turning into a vampire. Other than *choosing* to become one, being attacked by vampires is another way to turn into one.

Comment: so there must be a cure, right?

Comment: @PrasinShrestha: [This has already been answered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37247/how-do-i-cure-sanguinare-vampiris)

Answer (score 4):

If you *already* had Sanguinare Vampiris (check the **Active Effects** section of the **Magic** menu), you'll become a vampire three days after you contracted the disease, unless cured (such as with a Potion of Cure Disease). This can happen if you had recently been in combat with vampires. Declining Lord Harkon's gift has no bearing on this.

For more information, see [the UESP article on vampirism](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism).